# Enusuring spinner value selected, or button not allowed to be selected

Tags: java, android, validation, android-spinner

I am new to android studio and have created an app with a page that enables 2 spinners to be selected, a user enters a time and then an 'end time' is calculated. I am trying to add some validation to this page as when I click the 'VerifyButton' the app crashes as no fields have been selected. My intention is that when the user selects the 'VerifyButton' that an error message displays to ensure the spinner values have been filled in, meaning the app doesn't crash. I have tried a few methods within the onNothingSelected but it doesn't seem to work.. I wasn't sure if it needs to be in there or the VerifyButton? Thanks in advance!

Spinner Java

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateLine.this,
            R.layout.spinner_layout, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LineTypes));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
    spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long l) {


            switch (position2) {
                case 0:
                    quantity.setText("");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    quantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    timeadded = 10;
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    quantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    timeadded = 10;
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    quantity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    timeadded = 10;
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Package Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Package Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Package Type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }

    });



    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateLine.this,
            R.layout.spinner_layout, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PackageTypes));
    myAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
    spinner2.setAdapter(myAdapter2);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    quantity.setText("");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    quantity.setText(PackageType20);
                    timeadded = 28;
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");


                    break;
                case 2:
                    quantity.setText(PackageType30);
                    timeadded = 27;
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }


    });
```

VerifyButton Java

```
        VerifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            spinnerSelection = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
            spinnerSelection2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
            String q = quantity.getText().toString();
            String d = duration.getText().toString();

            DateTime datetime = new DateTime(yearNow, monthNow, dayNow, hourNow, minuteNow);
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EE dd MM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");
            String formattedtime = fmt.print(datetime);
            CalculateButton.setText(formattedtime);

            // Plus some hours, minutes, and seconds to the original DateTime.
            DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EE dd MM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");

            DateTime dateTime1 = datetime.plusHours(timeadded);
            String endtimecalc = fmt2.print(dateTime1);
            TextView endtime = findViewById(endtimetextView);
            endtime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            endtime.setText(endtimecalc);

            if (spinnerSelection !=null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter value",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            //INSERT DATA TO DATABASE
            boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(
                    spinnerSelection,
                    spinnerSelection2,
                    q,
                    d,
                    formattedtime,
                    endtimecalc);


            if (isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(CreateLine.this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(CreateLine.this, "This line is already Active!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
```

Comment: when your app crashes can you please tell what log said ?

Comment: it just crashes because no values have been entered, just want validation so when the button the spinner values must be selected

Comment: wat is view "quantity" & "duration"? Check this returns null or your db insert code causing an error. Spinner's default slected position is zero & onNothingselected() cannot fired because spinner have default selection.

Answer (score 0):

> After spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter) add;

```
spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter)
spinner.setSelection(-1);
```

> then on verify button click:

```
  if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == -1 || spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == -1 ){
         // showErrorMessage
  }
  else{
        //do your work
  }
```

**Do the same for spinner2**

Comment: have you tried adding lines at proper places? let me refactor my answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of your :

```
getApplicationContext()
```

with:

```
getContext()
```

and in following line instead of getApplicationContext():

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
```

Use your class name as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourClassName.this, Dashboard.class);
```

Class in which you are defining your verify button.

And in both of onNothingSelected methods set default value for spinner as:

```
ArrayList<String> list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LineTypes);

yourSpinner.setSelection(list[0]);
```

Also apply check instead of this:

```
 if (spinnerSelection !=null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter value",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

As:

```
 if (spinnerSelection.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty() || spinnerSelection.getSelectedItem().toString() == "" ) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter value",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Look last part of edited answer apply checks for your spinners in a way I defined above. This will work bro. Happy coding :). If it helps you let me know and for further assistance feel free to text me.